# Airflow - atomic create if not exists using xcom

Tags: python, airflow, workflow, race-condition

**Background**
I would like to have a kind of correlation id passed between operators to ensure data consistency within a single DAG and allow parallel runs of DAG at the same time.
What is more, I need to be able to partially rerun DAG at any time.
The best way to satisfy the above would be to check during operator execution if correlation id already exists using xcom (xcom_pull), if not initiate it (xcom_push).

**Problem**
in case if two operators would be executed as the first in DAG, there is a risk of the following race condition:

1. first reads correlation id
2. second reads correlation id
3. first pushes correlation id
4. second pushes correlation id

Resulting in correlation id inconsistency within DAG run

**Solution**
The method which would apply atomic check and create, i.e.:

```
xcom_get_or_create('key', 'default')
```

Is there a way to do that using xcom (without writing custom, underlying db specific SQL script)?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you please give an example of your use case, please. Are the correlation IDs generated an first task(s) of this dag?

Comment: I need to be able to partially rerun DAG at any time - so correlation id should be initiated from any node. Therefore having a first node in DAG which would initiate correlation id is not applicable here.

Comment: Omitting context: what I need is atomic get_or_create on xcom.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your use case but two ideas come to my mind: 1) use some branching operator 2) use custom operator `GetXComOp` that would return `self.xcom_pull(...) or your_default_value`.

Comment: I am sorry. I am still not able to understand the requirement. I am not a fan of xcom due to lack of predictability of xcoms in some cases, i have experienced.  So if you could help me understand your problem with a 'dummy' example, I will like to try.